# Find the right cup

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

A blind man went to a sorcerer to regain his sight. 
The sorcerer placed eight different colored cups in front of him, and said that one of these cups contained a magic drink while the other seven cups had poison in it. 
The cups were placed as the following picture:

[image]

The sorcerer told the blind man that the cups have the colors 
**Violet, Indigo, Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red, and White**.
Furthermore he gave the following hints:

> 1. The blue cup contains the magic drink,
> 2. The green cup is neither the leftmost nor the rightmost in its row.
> 3. The yellow and the red cup are opposite to each other.(row wise not beside each other)
> 4. The indigo cup is not in the top row.
> 5. The orange cup is beside the blue cup.
> 6. The white cup is leftmost or rightmost in its row.

Comment: What do you mean with "neightbours"? Can they be diagonally close to each other?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'neighbors'?

Comment: The clues aren't sufficient to give a unique solution because taking a mirror image of an acceptable solution along the column axis produces a different orientation of the cups which satisfies all the conditions ( assuming neighbours are also neighbours in the mirror image ).

Comment: Actually, a simpler construction is to swap orange and blue, which will also be a valid solution

Comment: Yeah indeed. So, probably the blind guy will drink poison even if he think he is right. RIP lol

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia they are opposite to each other.

Comment: If anything, "opposite to each other" makes even less sense than "neighbors" did....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This puzzle:

> Is simply broken! The puzzler should fix the hints or add more of them

Because:

> It has more than 8 Solutions, and in every solution the Blue Is in different place.
>  In conclusion the blind man has 1/8 chance to drink the magical drink.

Therefore:

> I think that the sorcerer doesn't have the magical drink, and he simply wants to kill the poor blind man! - Maybe to keep his reputation?-

The arrangements: 
(1)

> Blue   | Orange | Green  | White
>  Violet | Red    | Yellow | Indigo

(2) :

> Orange | Blue | Green  | white
>  Violet | Red  | Yellow | Indigo

(3) :

> White  | Green | Blue   | Orange
>  Violet | Red   | Yellow | Indigo

(4) :

> White  | Green | Orange  | Blue
>   Violet | Red   | Yellow  | Indigo

(5) :

> Violet | Green | Yellow  | Red
>   Blue   | Orange| Indigo  | White

(6) :

> Violet | Green | Yellow  | Red
>   Orange | Blue  | Indigo  | White

(7) :

> Violet | Green   | Yellow  | Red
>    Indigo | Orange  | Blue    | White

(8) :

> Violet | Green   | Yellow  | Red
>    White  |  Indigo | Orange  | Blue

Answer (score 3):

I think that

> This does not have a unique solution.

For example,

> The following solution works: 
>  
>  `White  | Green  | Orange | Blue
>  Indigo | Yellow | Red    | Violet`

And

> The following also works:
>  
>  `Blue   | Orange | Green  | White
>  Violet | Red    | Yellow | Indigo`

Comment: As i failed to ask a perfect question as per the people commenting , am chosing this as the right answer.